# Different children in recursive zod schema

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod

I would like to recreate this type in a zod schema:

```
type CommonParentData = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    ...
}

type SpecificChild = CommonParentData & {
    specific_property1: string
    specific_property2: number
    children: []
}

type Parent = CommonParentData & {
    children: Array<CommonParentData | SpecificChild>
}
```

Basically it's like a tree where each node has the same properties, except for the leaves that have some extra properties.

I've tried [following the docs](https://zod.dev/?id=recursive-types) in this way:

```
const commonSchema = z.strictObject({
    id: z.string(),
    name: z.string(),
    ...
});

const childSchema = commonSchema.merge(
    z.strictObject({
        specific_property1: z.string(),
        specific_property2: z.number(),
        children: z.tuple([]),
    }),
);

type Child = z.infer<typeof childSchema>;

type Parent = z.infer<typeof commonSchema> & {
    children: Array<Child | Parent>;
};

const schema: z.ZodType<Parent> = commonSchema.extend({
   children: z.lazy(() => schema.array()),
});
```

but it looks like it doesn't recognize the extra child properties (error `unrecognized_keys`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with `strictObject`. I actually don't see any docs explaining the specifics of how to use it, but at the time of writing, [this line of code](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/master/src/types.ts#L2302) shows that it adds a parsing error if it finds any other keys in the object. That means that you cannot extend this schema because the base schema is always going to fail.

I've updated your code to use the regular `z.object` schema and it all typechecks and parses for me:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

interface IBase {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface ISpecificChild extends IBase {
  specific_property1: string;
  specific_property2: number;
  children: [];
}

interface IParent extends IBase {
  children: Array<IParent | ISpecificChild>;
}

const baseSchema: z.ZodType<IBase> = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  name: z.string(),
});

const specificChildSchema: z.ZodType<ISpecificChild> = baseSchema.and(
  z.object({
    specific_property1: z.string(),
    specific_property2: z.number(),
    children: z.tuple([]),
  }),
);
const parentSchema: z.ZodType<IParent> = baseSchema.and(
  z.object({
    children: z.union([specificChildSchema, z.lazy(() => parentSchema)]).array(),
  }),
);

console.log(parentSchema.parse({
  id: '1',
  name: 'outer',
  children: [
    { id: '2', name: 'inner', specific_property1: 'test', specific_property2: 1, children: [] },
    { id: '3', name: 'nested', children: [
      { id: '4', name: 'nestedChild', specific_property1: 'test2', specific_property2: 2, children: [] },
    ]}
  ]
}));
```

Comment: So I guess there is no way of avoiding extra properties in this case, right?

Comment: No, I think you can get the behavior you want with `parentSchema.strict().parse` instead. You just need to delay the `strict` call until after you're done combining sub-schemas.

Comment: You'd need to add `strict` to the lazy parent schema call within `lazy` and to the `specificChildSchema` to make sure it's deeply strict

Comment: I'm not sure I understood it properly. Adding strict to any object results in the same `unrecognized_keys` error

Comment: I think I over simplified it in my explanation. I still think it should be possible, but I haven’t been able to get a working example with your schema. I’ll post an edit when I get it working